# Hyperlink from outlook/word to an Excel cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook, hyperlink

How can I create a create a hyperlink in Outlook/Word that links to a specific cell inside of an excel workbook? My use case is that I have an excel document with a list of tasks, and in outlook I want to create an outlook task for each one that links back to the exact cell where the task is listed.

I know that you can create a hyperlink from excel to another cell or cell range in another excel document using the bookmark option, however, this doesn't work when I try to do that outside of Excel. It gives me an error when I click the bookmark option.

I also tried manually adding the reference after the address in the hyperlink address bar, for example myworkbook.xlsx#Sheet1!B6, but this did not work properly either; it only opened up the workbook without going to the specific cell.

Comment: Well, when I googled your question, I got some fairly good results! One from Stack Exchange https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437469/how-do-i-create-a-hyperlink-from-word-to-excel-specific-cell-without-macros-vba and one from a common Excel tutorial site https://www.mrexcel.com/excel-tips/can-word-hyperlink-to-a-specific-sheet-and-cell-in-excel/ ... what did you find when YOU researched your question, what did you try as a result, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: As far as I know, in terms of inserting hyperlinks about Excel, hyperlinks created in outlook can only point to an entire excel. And I also tried in Excel, it seems that creating a hyperlink to a cell can only be done in the same excel. Above, It's impossible to realize this function through the outlook client itself.

By the way, maybe it can be realized through the combination of outlook client and VBA, such as creating a hyperlink to excel in the outlook client, with the role of some VBA scripts which can jump to the specificcell. Just provide an idea, which hasn't been realized yet.

Comment: Have you tried naming the cell?